# Terminal で設定した環境変数を、永続的にしたい

Tags: bash

JAVA_HOMEをterminalで変更したのですが、別タブのterminalでは初期の設定に戻ってしまいます。

Terminal で設定した環境変数を、永続的に反映させたい場合どうするればよいですか?

.bash_profileに直接書き込むのだと面倒なので、terminalで行いたいです。

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Answer (score 2):

普通にリダイレクトすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`' >> ~/.bash_profile
```